# javafx user-interface app can't access all the values from an ArrayList

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

So im developing a javafx gui that it should return all the valid values found in an ArrayList input range, but instead it's functionality its only valid for the latest value added,
so it's only returning the latest entry on the button click, i leave an example picture of the gui
as i hope this would help to clarify:
so if i add 2 different registration, 2 makes and 2 model and try and get the button search by regNo it only works with the latest entry not the previous one;
I leave the code for the setOnAction Method for the button

```
    public void searchByReg(javafx.event.ActionEvent e) {
    // clear the text field from the previous message
    txtOutput.clear();
    // get the car from the user through the car reg
    String carReg = txtReg.getText();
    // method to check if the field its empty
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++) {
        if (carReg.equalsIgnoreCase(cars.get(i).getRegNo())) {
            txtOutput.setText("You have selected \n" + cars.get(i));
            carFound = true;
        } else {
            txtOutput.setText("That car is not in our Database");
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Thank you for your help in Advance!!!

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, looks like you override text every time until last valid number.

```
    txtOutput.setText("You have selected");
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++) {
            if (carReg.equalsIgnoreCase(cars.get(i).getRegNo())) {
                txtOutput.append("\n" + cars.get(i));
                carFound = true;
            }
        }

    if(!carFound) {
       txtOutput.setText("That car is not in our Database");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a JavaFX issue, but just a muddled-up search loop.

There's better ways to do this since Java 8.  The following is much simpler and easier to read and debug:

```
public class LookupSample {

    record Car(String name, String regNo) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Car> cars = List.of(new Car("Mazda", "123"), new Car("Ford", "123"), new Car("Dodge", "789"));
        String carReg = "123";
        String result = cars.stream().filter(car -> car.regNo().equals(carReg)).map(Car::name).collect(Collectors.joining("\n\t ", "You have selected:\n\t", ""));
        System.out.println(result);
        boolean carFound = cars.stream().anyMatch(car -> car.regNo().equals(carReg));
        System.out.println("Car Found? " + carFound);
    }
}
```